# Accept and return lambda (lock wrapper)

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to accept any lambda, so that it can perform some operation safely under the `lock_guard` and then return anything, but using as shown below throws an error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

class Test {
    public:
        template<typename Ret>
        Ret DoLocked(std::function<Ret(Test&)> func) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*mtx);
            return func(*this);
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> mtx = std::make_unique<std::mutex>();
};

int main() {
    Test a;
    a.DoLocked([](Test &s) {
        std::cout << "in do locked" << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

````
[build] /some-path/test.cc:21:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test::DoLocked(main()::<lambda(Test&)>)’
[build]    21 |     });
[build]       |      ^
[build] /some-path/test.cc:9:13: note: candidate: ‘template<class Ret> Ret Test::DoLocked(std::function<Ret(Test&)>)’
[build]     9 |         Ret DoLocked(std::function<Ret(Test&)> func) {
[build]       |             ^~~~~~~~
[build] /some-path/test.cc:9:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
[build] /some-path/test.cc:21:6: note:   ‘main()::<lambda(Test&)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<Ret(Test&)>’
[build]    21 |     });```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily solved by getting rid of `std::function` and making the function parameter a template parameter.  That would look like

```
template<typename Func>
auto DoLocked(Func func) -> decltype(func(*this)) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*mtx);
    return func(*this);
}
```

The reason it doesn't work with the `std::function` is that a lambda expression does not create a `std::function`.   It creates a object of an unnamed class type that has an `operator()` defined with the body of the lambda expression.  Because of this, template deduction fails as it is expecting a `std::function` but that is not what is being provided.

Comment: Isn't that `auto` ill-formed in C++11?

Comment: @PasserBy Woops, missed the C++11 tag.  Should be better now.

Comment: This works in the minimal reproducible I gave, but in my use (DoLocked is called from within another lambda). I get > error: use of ‘auto ev::Store::DoLocked(Func) before deduction of auto

Comment: @t348575 I would need to see a [mre] in order to help with that.

Comment: ok nvm it works with the `decltype`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to accept any lambda, so that it can perform some operation safely under the lock_guard

This is completely wrong assumption which will lead to deadlock.

Locks are to protect consistency of some specific data.
Those data usually are fields of some single class.

Now critical section should protect this data and must not invoke any arbitrary code. Why? Since arbitrary code can contain other critical sections. This means that you do not have control on order of locks which are acquired. As a result small unrelated change to code will lead to hard to remove dead lock.